# CoreData - Use AppDelegate, singleton or property on viewcontroller for managedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, core-data, uiviewcontroller

What way is the preferred to handle a `CoreData` `managedObjectContexts`? And why?

I often see three different ways, and a bonus way:

- Declare in `AppDelegate` and let the view controller depend on the AppDelegate
- A `sharedManager singleton class`
- `Property on each view controller` and let the parent view controller set it
- A `category` for UIViewController that expose the `shared manageObjectContext`.

What's the pro's and con's with each approach in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

> Declare in `AppDelegate` and let the view controller depend on the `AppDelegate`

Nasty. The app delegate shouldn't be involved as the data model isn't an application level delegation activity. It's also inappropriate for all of the other classes to be dependent upon the app delegate.

Apple take this option in sample code because it's easy, but that doesn't make it right.

> A sharedManager singleton class

Provides good knowledge management, a good location to put migration logic (if required outside the mapping model), and can abstract the application at large away from any remote synchronisation aspects in the app.

Lots of people dislike singletons (global state), but they do have their uses.

> Property on each view controller and let the parent view controller set it

Pretty nice - but dependent upon where the (root) parent is getting the MOC from in the first place.

> A category for `UIViewController` that expose the shared manageObjectContext

Again, depends where the MOC is originating from. This hides the knowledge better than explicit references all over the code, but cross coupling to the wrong class is still bad.

Comment: I suggest to make shared PersistentStoreCoordinator instead.

Comment: Can somebody explain why Apple do that: Declaring core data in AppDelegate when we start a new project and tick the Core Data option? Since you're saying that declaring Core Data in AppDelegate is a big no?

Answer (score 0):

I do none of those.

Anyway, standing up the entire stack can take a fair bit of time, especially if a migration is involved.  Thus, I always construct the stack asynchronously, and fire a notification with the stack has been completely established.

Interested parties can listen to the notification, and start using the stack at that point in time.

Most apps only have one stack, and it can be kicked off in the app delegate.  You can listen for the notification in your main view controller's `viewDidLoad` method (which will have already fired but the time `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` runs).

You have the added benefit of a responsive UI while the stack is being created.  The only thing you have to do is make sure the UI is reasonable without data (which is a better alternative than having it be non-responsive while the stack is loading).

Comment: Personally, I think you're over complicating this. It's acceptable to wait a tiny bit as the app loads by showing a splash screen. If you want to handle this async you may have to display an activity indicator if the user must wait for the stack to load in the main view, which is a bad trade off. Anyhow, I don't  think you answered the question here. The OP is asking  for the best practice on communicating with the context. Should you call back to the AppDelegate, pass around a reference, etc. Your answer is addressing something different.

Answer (score 0):

My view is that you should move the stack out of the AppDelegate and make a separate class that you could kick off from the AppDelegate. Pass a reference to this data class down the viewController hierarchy if you like. This way your AppDelegate isn't responsible for the stack, and you can test your classes by passing in a mock data object. I think you want to avoid creating a dependency between your view controllers and the AppDelegate. Your ViewControllers shouldn't need to have knowledge of your AppDelegate. That's a totally unnecessary dependency. Putting the dependency in a category doesn't solve the problem either. By moving the stack outside the AppDelegate you have the option to make the stack class a singleton if you don't want to rely on the AppDelegate to kick it off. This is a good use of the singleton pattern IMO.

Here are 2 gists, the first in Objc and the second in Swift that should get you started. In Swift I made it a singleton straight off.

https://gist.github.com/philosopherdog/4219a1b8f446acf8c8dc

https://gist.github.com/philosopherdog/cab11bb626f3bbe776a22ea408c900e1